# ASP.net core Razor page file upload with AJAX Post to IFormFile handler returns 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I have a very simple task that just needs to upload a file and have the AJAX post it to the Index page:

```
    <input type="file" id="file-selector" accept=".txt">
```

Associated Javascript:

```
const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load', event => {
        const txtFile = event.target.result;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ControlData?handler=FileUploader",
            error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText); },
            data: txtFile,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": "@token" }
        });
    });
    reader.readAsText(file);
});
```

Code in /Pages/ControlData/Index.cshtml.cs:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostFileUploaderAsync(IFormFile model)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

The app runs fine, the file is selected, but the POST call always gets a 404:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The app runs fine, the file is selected, but the POST call always gets a 404

Please check if you configured page route with route data parameter, like `@page "{title}"` etc, which cause HTTP 404 error.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-a-page-route
- https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-templates

> needs to upload a file and have the AJAX post it to the Index page

> Code in /Pages/ControlData/Index.cshtml.cs

> public IActionResult OnPostFileUploaderAsync(IFormFile model)

To post selected file to your handler `OnPostFileUploaderAsync`, you can try modify the code like below.

```
<script>
    const fileSelector = document.getElementById('file-selector');
    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        
        //post the selected file through formdata
        //instead of using the readAsText() method to read the contents of the specified file

        var txtFile = new FormData();
        txtFile.append("model", file);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ControlData/Index?handler=FileUploader",
            error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText); },
            data: txtFile,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": "@token" }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fei, spot on, there is a page parameter.  So if I change the post url to include it (e.g., /ControlData/4?handler=FileUploader), I now get an http 400 as opposed to 404.  So a little closer.  I'm just not sure how to diagnose the 400, it's a very vague error to begin with.  everything I can see in debug mode with headers and data looks ok, but then again my client-side skills are lacking.  If you have any suggestions let me know, but otherwise thanks again for the response.

Comment: Hi @Mike., have you tried to post the selected file through formdata as I mentioned in my reply?

Comment: Hi Fei, yes, I copied the code from above and adapted it to my url path, still getting the 400.  Will keep digging and post any updates if I get it resolved.  Thanks very much.